# Bitnami LAPP installation error

Tags: installation, bitnami

I am trying to install Bitnami LAPP stack (Linux Apache PostgreSQL PHP) on a centos 6.4 64bit operating system. In the Readme file, following system configuration is expected:

---

1. REQUIREMENTS

To install Bitnami LAPP stack you will need:

```
- Intel x86 or compatible processor
- Minimum of 256 MB RAM
- Minimum of 150 MB hard drive space
- An x86 Linux operating system
```

### - TCP/IP protocol support

During the installation, I receive a warning whic says that I need at least 2000MB memory available. (In the readme file, it is said that the minimum requirment is 256MB)

After choosing the installation parameters, I receive a storage error but I have more storage than explained in the readme file

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, could you post the RAM and the free disk space in your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by the Bitnami team. I think it was a definition problem in the seup environment.